# Draw text in corners with graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I have a very simple graph:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=rect];
    rankdir=LR;
    A -> B
}
```

It outputs as I expect:

[image: Simple output]

However, I need to place unique numbers in each corner of both A and B. I am currently only aware of `xlabel`, but from what I gather can only be used once and cannot be specified in a particular region. So how can I accomplish writing numbers in each corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest versions of Graphviz support HTML styling of nodes, including tables ("newer than mid-November 2003", that is). So you can make a 3x3 table like this:

[image: a node with number in each corner]

Source:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=rect];
    rankdir=LR;
    A [shape=none label=<
      <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0">
      <TR><TD>1</TD><TD></TD><TD>2</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD COLSPAN="3" BORDER="1">A</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD>3</TD><TD></TD><TD>4</TD></TR>
      </TABLE>
    >];
    A -> B
}
```

Tested with http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/; it also works with my local installed version (2.38.0).

See [Graphviz: Node Shapes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html) for the full set of supported HTML, and examples.

Comment: Is it possible to put the numbers outside instead of inside? Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: Sure, see my updated code: make all borders go away and just add them to the center cell. *Do* read that documentation page if you want more to change.